# How to add S.O. Number field in invoice of Quickbooks desktop. I am unable to find it in the api reference of invoice add

Tags: c#, xml, quickbooks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <InvoiceAddRq requestID="2">
            <InvoiceAdd>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>80000002-1572341266</ListID>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2019-10-26</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>12:01 PM</RefNumber>
                <PONumber>65</PONumber>
                <SalesRepRef>
                    <ListID>80000001-1572347694</ListID>
                </SalesRepRef>
                <FOB>gdgdgs</FOB>
                <Memo>Memo Customer Memo</Memo>
                <Other>OtherInfo</Other>
                <InvoiceLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <ListID>8000000E-1572333361</ListID>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                    <Other1>India</Other1>
                    <Other2>Punjab</Other2>
                </InvoiceLineAdd>
            </InvoiceAdd>
        </InvoiceAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

I have formed above xml to add invoice in Quickbooks desktop but I am unable to find any field named S.O. Number in api reference of Quickbooks desktop. Kindly help me with that as I am stuck with this issue and I am unable to get any help in the api reference documentation of Quickbooks Desktop.

Comment: Is the "Purchase Order" and "Sales Order" the same number?

Comment: No both are different -- @@jdweng

Answer (score 0):

You can add a LinkedTxnID element to the InvoiceAddRq to accomplish this.

```
<LinkToTxnID >IDTYPE</LinkToTxnID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
```

You can also link specific invoice lines to sales order lines by adding the element below to InvoiceLineAdd.

```
<LinkToTxn> <!-- optional -->
    <TxnID >IDTYPE</TxnID> <!-- required -->
    <TxnLineID >IDTYPE</TxnLineID> <!-- required -->
</LinkToTxn>
```

In both cases, note that the ID you need to specify is the linked transaction's ListID, not the RefNumber.

If you are using the QBSDK, you can do the equivalent as follows:

```
// Add link at transaction level
InvoiceAddRq.LinkToTxnIDList.Add("000000-0000000000");

// Add link at line level
InvoiceLineAdd.LinkToTxn.TxnID.SetValue("000000-0000000000");
InvoiceLineAdd.LinkToTxn.TxnLineID.SetValue("000000-0000000000");
```

For more information, see the [IDN Onscreen Reference](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html)